# Commutating Annihilators with a beamsplitter

Tags: quantum-computer

I am reading Nielsen and Chuang on P. 291, for anyone interested in the origin of my question.

Given an annihilator $a$ and its corresponding creator $a^\dagger$ such that $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$ and another annihilator $b$ with creator $b^\dagger$, an argument in a proof claims the following:

Let $G = a^\dagger b - ab^\dagger$. Then, $[G,a] = -b$ and $[G,b] = a$.

I don't see how these two relations hold. Can someone please point me in the right direction or prove them?

Thank you SOCommunity!

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in a now-deleted comment by [Luboš Motl](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1236/lubo%c5%a1-motl):

> Hi, just use $[XY,Z]=XYZ-ZXY = XYZ-XZY+XZY-ZXY = X[Y,Z]+[X,Z]Y$ and the basic commutators $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ and similarly for $b$ while other commutators vanish. You will see that from the right hand side, only one term survives and it gives you what you need.